# Do 240 volt dryers need to be AFCI protected

Tags: 240v, afci

Under 2014 NEC do 240 volt dryer sockets need to be AFCI protected?

I see paragraphs specifying that single phase 125 volt circuits must be protected, but I have not found specifications for two phase 240 volt circuits.

Comment: Are you referring to the 2017 NEC?

Comment: Have clarified the question to specify 2014 NEC. However if there have been recent changes to this requirement I would be happy to hear about them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No -- the 2014 NEC only calls out AFCIs for *120V, 15 and 20A* outlets -- the dryer is 240V, so it doesn't need an AFCI.

> **210.12 Arc-Fault Circuit-Interrupter Protection.** Arc-
>   fault circuit-interrupter protection shall be provided as required in 210.12(A) (B), and (C). The arc-fault circuit interrupter shall be installed in a readily accessible location.
>
> **(A) Dwelling Units.** All 120-volt, single-phase, 15- and
>   20-ampere branch circuits supplying outlets or devices installed in dwelling unit kitchens, family rooms, dining
>   rooms, living rooms, parlors, libraries, dens, bedrooms,
>   sunrooms, recreation rooms, closets, hallways, laundry areas, or similar rooms or areas shall be protected by any of
>   the means described in 210.12(A)(l) through (6):

Comment: Has this changed in NEC 2020?

Comment: @cryptic0 -- the only change would be requiring *GFCI* for dryer outlets, but I'd have to look to see if that's a NEC 2020 change or not coming until 2023